# What's the difference between 'taxing' and 'tiring'?

Tags: difference

What are the nuances to 'taxing' and 'tiring'? Say, is there any difference between these two sentences?

> 1. It is kind of taxing to wield this demon lord slaying holy sword.
> 2. It is kind of tiring to wield this demon lord slaying holy sword.

Comment: Have you compared the definitions of these words in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the same, but I think taxing implies something specific is really being lost. Say the person has a limited amount of energy due to some temporary illness like covid. Or maybe there's really money being lost from the activity. Tiring can sometimes be used figuratively like it doesn't really tire you out, but you really hate doing that particular task so it's as if the task is tiring.